# generate 100 sample at given rate

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i want to  generate 100 samples of sinusoid in matlab with frequency 0.2Hz and sampling rate 2Hz. ,for this i used following code

```
f=0.2;
 fs=2;
 A=100;%suppose that amplitude is 100
 q=20;
 t=0:1/fs:50;
 x=A*sin(2*pi*f*t+q);
```

but length of x is 101,not 100;so what would be correct form for generate exactly 100  sample data?i have calculated approximately what should be upper limit to get sample data with size 100;for this i have chose 50;but is there any other method  for this?of course i can calculate period

```
T=1/f=5;
```

but how can i use it?should i multiply it by fs or vice versa fs should be divided by period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in `t=0:1/fs:50;` you start from 0, which explain why you get more than 100 samples.

One way to solve it:

```
 number_of_sample_data = 100;
 f=0.2;
 fs=2;
 A=100;%suppose that amplitude is 100
 q=20;
 t=0:1/fs:((number_of_sample_data-1)*1/fs);
 x=A*sin(2*pi*f*t+q);
```

which gives:

```
 >> length(x)

 ans =
 100
```

Comment: like this one yes?http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/changing-audio-sampling-rate.html

Comment: for curious, is it there any  other method?

Comment: I don't think so, this is pretty standard.

Comment: use the linspace function as mentioned by @horchler below.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `linspace` function, i.e.:

```
number_of_sample_data = 100;
f = 0.2;
fs=2;
A=100;%suppose that amplitude is 100
q=20;
tf=number_of_sample_data/fs; %final time
t=linspace(0,tf,number_of_sample_data);
x=A*sin(2*pi*f*t+q);
```

Note, however, that `linspace` will not always give exactly the same numeric values as @Franck Dernoncourt's more efficient solution. This is because some numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating point and `linspace` builds the vector slightly differently. Type `edit linspace` to see how. For the particular values you gave, @Franck Dernoncourt's solution is both more efficient and more precise because 1/fs=0.5 can be represented exactly in floating point.